Autosave every few minutes in LWC Salesforce
I am trying to do an autosave of records in my array (which has the list of records to be updated in Salesforce) periodically.
I am calling the handleUpdate function in JS , which calls the apex method to save. I am not sure, if this is the right approach to achieve the autosave in lwc.
I could not find any posts related to autosave in LWC. Appreciate your help & directions.
Challenges with this approach:

this.finalUpdateRecs (array which has the list of record, when any changes are made by the user ) is always printing as undefined in the handleUpdate function, when triggered by setInterval function
If someone closes the lwc page,setinterval is still running, wondering how could we detect if the LWC screen is closed/tab is closed, so that we can call the clearinterval

Below is my code snippet:
  initialTimer = 3000;
    timer;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.callTimer();
    }

    callTimer(){
        this.timer = setInterval(this.handleUpdate,this.initialTimer);
    }

    handleUpdate(event) {
       
        if(this.finalUpdateRecs && this.finalUpdateRecs.length > 0){

            updateCheckList({ recordsToUpdate: this.finalUpdateRecs })

            .then() =>{}
            .catch(error =>{})

        }
       
   }

